# op amp current source oscillating

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, current, oscillator, source

I know this topic has been discussed a lot, but there seems to be varying opinions about the solutions..

The problem is we are trying to make a current source with an op-amp driving a FET as the load. Our goal is to have a fairly high bandwidth for the regulating loop(couple of 100kHz?), but the output of the op-amp is oscillating.

[image: First iteration]

Using a ADA4807 and a ST P36nE06 mosfet. 
The values for the series(R2) and parallel(R3) resistors were chosen from the op-amps datasheet about driving capacitive load.

There is a 100nF bypass cap very close to the supply pins, and a 2uF cap also.

We have tried a few things which includes:

1. Upping the series resistor to 50ohm or 100ohm. Did not fix it.
2. Adding 1nF cap from output to -vin of the op-amp, together with a 10k or 100k resistor (miller integrator). Did not help.
3. Changing the 10mOhm resistor to 100mOhm. Did not help either.

The prototype is done on verroboard. I don't know if that could be an issue?

I would think this op-amp would be able to drive any capacitive load, but it doesn't seem to work for us. What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80297/discussion-on-question-by-linkyyy-op-amp-current-source-oscillating).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The op-amp's capacitive load drive stated in the data sheet is 15pF giving rise to an overshoot of 30%. Yes, you can improve this by using a series resistor to drive the capacitor (The MOSFET is about 2 nF) but you are still driving capacitance within the closed loop feedback network and that makes adding a resistor pointless - you just shift the phase further and make it oscillate at a lower frequency.

In a closed loop situation like this you have to look at the op-amp's open-loop gain and recognize that it is never ideal and might have a phase margin that is quite poor at high frequencies. A poor phase margin means that negative feedback is close to becoming positive feedback and an extra bit of RC filtering (due to the gate-source capacitance) can easily tip the balance from stability to oscillation.

You need to put a capacitor from op-amp output to the inverting input and put a resistor (try 1 kohm) from that input (pin 4) to the feedback point on the current sense resistor. You may be lucky and get the bandwidth you want but there is no guarantee.

Comment: Hmm alright, it makes sense then why the series resistor didn't change anything then..
I believe the input capacitance of the mosfet is 2-3nF actually

Comment: Step voltage incremental prop delay is 100ps/pF load and output impedance rises with slew rate.  Yet the FET Ciss is very nonlinear.  I would insert an Emitter Follower before the gate with Re=180 Ohms and keep all jumpers as short as possible. And use 10V step input reduced to 100mV with ~500:5 Ohm divider.

Comment: @Linkyyy yes it is more like 2 nF - I have corrected my answer and added more explanation as to why it becomes an oscillator.

Comment: @Linkyyy if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.